# Do video/graphics cards work at their "peak" output for connected monitors all of the time?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a Gigabyte GTX 770 and am planning on connecting two 1920x1080 monitors, a 1440x900 monitor, and a 2560 x 1600 HP LP3065 monitor.

I am wondering if I connect all 4 monitors to my video card (it has enough ports), will my graphics card constantly be working all of these screens regardless of whether I have the monitors themselves turned off or on? I just need to use the HP LP3065 monitor some times and NOT all of the time, so I don't want to subject my video card to extra "wear-and-tear" over the long run by connecting it to my GTX 770 with already three monitors...

Comment: Make sure that you can actually run 4 monitors on it. Often cards can only output up to 2 DVI, HDMI, or VGA signals, and any additional signals must be displayport.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a display connected, and the OS is configured to output to that display, the graphics card will be outputting to that display whether that display is on or off.

However, just outputting to a display isn't exactly a gpu-heavy task, and if it did cause any wear and tear, it would be negligable.